# elasticsearch query dsl show products with higher product quantity at the top

Tags: elasticsearch, querydsl

i want to search products based on some filters and a keyword which in my code identified by **q**. what i trying to do is to show products which product_quantity is not equal to zero at the top.
this is my current query.

```
"query":{
     "bool":{
        "filter":[
           {
              "term":{
                 "status":{
                    "value":1
                 }
              }
           },
           {
              "range":{
                 "published_at":{
                    "lt":"2022-06-21 14:23:58"
                 }
              }
           }
        ],
        "must_not":[
           {
              "terms":{
                 "categories.id":[
                    "2754",
                    "2377"
                 ]
              }
           }
        ],
        "should":[
           {
              "multi_match":{
                 "fields":[
                    "title",
                    "code",
                    "seo.title",
                    "categories.title",
                    "subtitle",
                    "part_number"
                 ],
                 "boost":10,
                 "type":"phrase",
                 "tie_breaker":0.3,
                 "query":"cpu"
              }
           },
           {
              "multi_match":{
                 "fields":[
                    "title",
                    "seo.title",
                    "categories.title",
                    "subtitle"
                 ],
                 "type":"most_fields",
                 "fuzziness":"AUTO",
                 "query":"cpu"
              }
           }
        ]
     }
  },
```

and this is my script sort query:

```
{
        "_script": {
            "type": "number",
            "script": {
                "lang": "painless",
                "source": "if(Math.abs(doc['product_quantity'].value) > 0) { 1 } else { 1 }"
            },
            "order":"desc"
        }
    },
    {
        "_score":"desc"
    }
```

but it is not accurate.
my question is what is the best way to search with analyzer and set higher score to products with higher than zero quantity to show at the top.

Comment: do you want to get product on top which have highest `product_quantity` right ?

Comment: @SagarPatel yes but keep in mind that i want to show relevant products with product quantity higher than zero (not the highest) at the top

Comment: why you are returning `1` for both the case in if condition. it should be `0` from else right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sort clause should be like below, `else` clause should have value `0` and not `1`:

```json
"sort": [
    {
      "_script": {
            "type": "number",
            "script": {
                "lang": "painless",
                "source": "if(Math.abs(doc['qty'].value) > 0) { 1 } else { 0 }"
            },
            "order":"desc"
        }
    },
    {
        "_score":"desc"
    }
  ]
```

Comment: what a dummy mistake. thanks mate